# Nhibernate pre-set id on entity, can't get it to persist

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, orm

I have an entity `Account` that, under normal circumstances, will have its Guid Id generated by NHibernate.  However, there are a few `Account` Id's that I want to "hard-code", accounts that will be referenced everywhere and serve very specific functions.

I would like to define these objects in a configuration file, complete with a pre-configured Guid Id, and when starting my application, check to see if these accounts exist in the database.  If they do not, I want to add them exactly as they are.  If they are there, I want to overwrite database version and persist the properties set from the configuration file.

I thought to myself, this seems to be what `ISession.Merge` is for, but the objects are not persisted.  Then I thought to myself, this must be what `ISession.Persist` is for, but that throws an exception complaining about persisting a detached object.  `ISession.SaveOrUpdate` likewise does not persist the objects.

What do I need to do to persist these few "pre-fab" objects in NHibernate?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that sometimes you want to generate the ID yourself and other times you want NH to generate the ID. I think you will need to create a custom `IIdentifierGenerator`, but I've never done this myself.

Answer (score 4):

You can save an entity with a specific id using the overloaded  Save(object obj, object id); [NHibernate ISession](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/ISession.cs)

```
/// <summary>
/// Persist the given transient instance, using the given identifier.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="obj">A transient instance of a persistent class</param>
/// <param name="id">An unused valid identifier</param>
void Save(object obj, object id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put these predefined Guids in string constants. From string constants you can create Guid instances. In app startup query the DB for objects with these guids. If found update the objects and do an update in DB. If not found create object instances with predefined guids and do an insert.

In other words, there is nothing special about these "pre-fab" objects. Treat them as regular objects as any other that do not have a predefined Ids.

UPDATE: It's not so simple. NHibernate will probably try to fill in ID with new Guid and the questions is how to tell NHibernate that sometimes you want to do this yourself ?

Session.Merge will first try to load the entity from Db and if it finds one it will merge in-memory instance with a from-db instance. Otherwise it will add new instance to DB.

You can always add this predefined entities directly using ADO.NET manually skipping NH altogether, but it's not a very nice solution.

Comment: It sounds simple, right?  That's basically what I did (less the constant string part, but I don't think that's really relevant), but NHibernate would not persist them.

Answer (score 0):

If your mapping says NH will generate the Id, then you can't insert specific Ids using NH.

Either use an ad-hoc SqlQuery, or create a partially modified mapping configuration for initialization that has an `assigned` Id.